# CP Session - keep alive or override timeout behavior?

Tags: control-panel, sessions, ee5

I need a quick point in the right direction. This is for EE-5.3.X

I built out a SAML plugin to log in users using our IDP/SSO setup which works great, but i had a tiny oversight, the CP session timeout. The setup is set to use Cookies Only for both CP and Web.

I need to either keep the EE session/cookie alive forever ( preferably without overriding the sessions.php core file ) **OR** override that re-login overlay to force a user to be logged out via SLO redirect.

So how do I hook into the EE's CP session timeout overlay if that's the path i'm taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to use "remember me" functionality and override the config to set the session length to like a year: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/config/config-files.html#remember-me-expiration

Comment: That's exactly what i ended up doing after looking at how session.php file handles things. TLDR when i initialize my plugin i load the remember library and just do ee()->remember->create() and then on logout i do ee()->remember->delete() which solves my issue. So yea, you're correct that works great!